# Casting an int array into a char pointer in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting, char

I ran through these few lines of code in C:

```
int tab[]={4,6,8,9,20};
char *p;     
p=(char*)tab
```

And the question was how to print the value of 20 using the pointer p.

So i used a for loop to see what's going on with p

```
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%d ",p[i]);
    }
```

and i got this output:

```
4 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 20 0 0 0
```

i want to understand the logic behind those zeros appearing.

Comment: What else would you expect to be shown, when you seem to know that `char` and `int` have different sizes? Do you know how numbers are stored in memory?

Comment: `int` uses 4 bytes, `char` uses 1 byte. So you're seeing each of the 4 bytes in the numbers when you use `p[i]`.

Comment: @Badie Sakka, Try `int tab[]={0x04030201, 0x08070605, 0x0C0B0A09, 0x100F0E0D, 0x14131211};`.  What does your code print?

Answer (score 4):

You are almost certainly using an architecture where `int` is 4 bytes, and a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) architecture where the "smallest" byte is stored first.

So the `int` value `4` is stored as:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|  4 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

The `int` value `20` gets stored as:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 20 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Your entire array in memory looks like:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  4 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  8 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  9 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 20 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now, when you iterate over those 20 bytes as characters (and thus one byte at a time) the results should no longer be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

On your machine, the `sizeof` an `int` is `4` bytes, and `sizeof` a `char` is by definition `1`.

So with `p`, you're printing an `int` byte by byte.

---

*"And the question was how to print the value of 20 using the pointer p."*

---

As for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void) 
{
     int tab[] = {4, 6, 8, 9, 20};
     char *p = 0;     
     
     /* The type that & returns is a 
     *  pointer type, in this case, a 
     *  pointer to the 4th element of 
     *  the array.
     */
     p = (char*) &tab[4];
     
     /* As %d expects an int, we cast 
     *  p to an int *, and then 
     *  dereference it. 
     */
     printf("%d\n", *(int *)p);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Output:

```
20
```

Edit: The above code is endian-dependent.